# Regular Expression For Time string

Tags: php, regex

I have string like Following,

```
10:00 AM 09:00 PM 7:00 PM
```

I want to convert it into an array like below

```
[10:00 AM , 09:00 PM ,7:00PM]
```

I am trying with following

```
((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ?([AaPp][Mm]))
```

is there any way to get as i want an array? I am using PHP as my Server side Script

Comment: Show your current code. What is the actual issue? Actually, your regex works well as [it matches the strings you want](https://regex101.com/r/YAtgF1/2).

Comment: You can split using this regex - [`(?<=[AaPp][Mm])`](https://regex101.com/r/kAcG07/1) or [`\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\s*[aApP][mM]\K`](https://regex101.com/r/kAcG07/2)